# I have error in swift loop

Tags: swift, loops

am new in swift I tried to make loop like this

```
for var z = 0 ; z <= 25 ; z = z + 5 {

print (z)
}
```

put it gives me this error

> Loop.playground:5:1: error: C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `where` clause!

```
for z in 0...25 where z % 5 == 0 {
    print(z)
}
```

It basically filters out `z` values and it only leaves the `z` values that are divisible by 5, which is what you want.

This is wayyyy more swifty than the C-style for loop.

Another way to do this is with `stride`:

```
for i in stride(from: 0, through: 25, by: 5) {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: The first version may look "Swifty" but is *very ineffective.* `z` is incremented in steps of one, and an additional `%` operation is needed for each value to determine if the body should be executed or not. `stride()` – as in the linked-to duplicate – is a better solution.

Comment: thank you for your help, it works well but this is if I want to increase the number by 5, what if I want to decreases the number? for example from 10 to 0 ?

Comment: @zainab simple, stride from 10 through 0 by -1!